# Creating a customized "default" button in Expression Blend + WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, expression-blend, controltemplate

I'm about 95% of the way to getting what I need but still have some issues. Basically I'd like the default style of all Button controls (to use when dragging a Button to the form using Expression Blend) to behave as below:

On mouse over - change the button font's coloring to a gradient AND increase the size of the font by 2 points more than the font size the control is assigned in it's "normal" state. The size increase is important as the "buttons" don't have any border, they're just plain text with a drop shadow.

On click - again change the font coloring, remove a drop shadow to make it appear depressed (the size would still remain the "normal" font size + 2 points)

My current method is giving me some issues and it's a bit too much code to post here, so I'm hoping to get a few suggestions for alternative approaches from someone with more experience at this.

I'd *prefer* not to have a totally custom Button control (like "CustomButton") and to simply override the regular default "Button" control's appearance/style since it'll be the only type of button in the application. But if a new class/control is the only way, I'll give that a try instead.

Ex.

```
<Button Content="Button1"/>
<Button Content="Button2" FontSize="18"/>
<Button Content="Button3" FontSize="24"/>
```

On mouseover, the fontsize should go to +2 larger than each button's assigned size. Right now I'm doing this by overlaying a TextBlock on top of the button's real text (with a few bindings), but it's not quite working yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are asking two questions here:

1. How to change the button's appearance on MouseOver
2. How to automatically apply this to all buttons

Regarding #1: No need for a specialized custom control - the easiest way to do this in WPF is by using a Style (with a property trigger for IsMouseOver).

As for #2: By making your Style a keyless resource (not specifying a resource key), it will be applied to all controls in scope matching the target type.

Here's an example of a style you can place in your Window's or App's resources:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                     Value="True">
                <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1.05" ScaleY="1.05"/>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Setter Property="Foreground">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <LinearGradientBrush>
                            <GradientStop Color="CornflowerBlue"
                                          Offset="0"/>
                            <GradientStop Color="DarkSlateBlue"
                                          Offset="1"/>
                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
        <Setter Property="RenderTransformOrigin"
                Value=".5,.5"/>
    </Style>
```

Note that this style will *not* increase the font size by 2 - instead, it scales the entire button by 5%. This might indeed be the better (and easier) solution to what you have in mind. If you absolutely need to *increase* the relative font size (instead of assigning an absolute, new font size), it's a bit trickier but can be done too.

Comment: I started doing something similar before, but couldn't get the button to enlarge and still remain centered. The upper-left corner remains at the same coordinates when it should be slightly shifted up/left a few pixels (depending on the zoom level). It doesn't have quite the same visual effect as when the center remains in the same location. This would probably work if I could get past that. I wasn't even looking at triggers, just states (which only seems to apply to controls), so that's something new I can play with.

Comment: Got it, in Blend under the scale transforms if you click "use relative values", it keeps the text centered. Much simpler than the path I was going down!

Comment: Actually, that's what setting the RenderTransformOrigin property to 0.5, 0.5 is for - making the Button's center the ScaleTransform's origin.

Comment: Yep, I noticed in the xaml. Thanks